# Allocating memory for an array

Tags: c++, oop, file-io, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read numbers from a file and store then in an array using dynamic memory.  When I try to print a member of the array, it is showing the address instead of the actual contents.

```
// CLASS METHOD IMPLEMENTATIONS
#include "DataHousing.h"

// CONSTRUCTORS
DataHousing::DataHousing() {

}

void DataHousing::FillArray() {
    int tempIn = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // attempt to open the file with read permission
    ifstream inputHandle("NumFile500.txt", ios::in);

    // count how many numbers are in each file
    if (inputHandle.is_open() == true) {
        while (!inputHandle.eof()) {
            inputHandle >> tempIn;
            count++;
        }

        // allocate memory for array
        int* pFileContents = new int[count];

        // fill array
        while (!inputHandle.eof()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                inputHandle >> pFileContents[i];
            }
        }

        cout << &pFileContents[2];
    }

    else {
        cout << "error";
    }


}
```

This is my first time attempting anything like this and I am pretty stuck.  What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You're printing the address `cout << &pFileContents[2]`. By the way why not use [vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? if you want dynamic memory

Comment: @skrrrt After some research it definitely seems like vectors would be the best way to go but for some reason, we have not learned about vectors in my class.  I am only supposed to use the tools that we have learned so far in class so that is why I am not using them.  Trust me, that after this semester I will be taking the time to learn vectors in my own time but I need to be able to complete this project with out using vectors.

Answer (score 2):

The unary `&` operator is to retrieve an address, so it is quite natural that it is showing the address.

To display the contents, remove the `&` in `cout << &pFileContents[2];` and have it display the contents.

Also the counting part of your code

```
while (!inputHandle.eof()) {
    inputHandle >> tempIn;
    count++;
}
```

has two mistakes.

Firstly, you are incrementing `count` without the last reading was successful.

Secondly, you are trying to read from `ifstream` that is already reached to EOF.
You have to clear the EOF flag and seek to the beginning of the file like this:

In conclusion, the counting part should be:

```
while (inputHandle >> tempIn) {
    count++;
}
inputHandle.clear();
inputHandle.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
```

Comment: I made these changes and now I am getting an error code that "Readig invalid data from 'pFileContents': the readable size is 'count*4' bytes, but '12' bytes may be read."  The error is on the line

cout << pFileContents[2];

Comment: Hmmm, [reduced version of the code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WMhxBDkgfn9oDj1C) works. What is the contents of the text file to read?

Comment: It is a list of integers.  The particular file I am working with now has 500 integers.  One per line.  I also have a file with 100,000 integers that this class needs to also work for

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to print the required value using:

```
cout << &pFileContents[2];
```

Since `pFileContents` is an array, `pFileContents[2]` will access the second element (value) of the same.
But since you've prepended `&` before the element, it is going to print the address of the second element of the array.

In order to print the value of the second element of the array, just use:

```
cout << pFileContents[2];
```

Notice the difference in the later code, we haven't used `&` just after `cout <<`